# sql error - data truncation for datetime - using java/hibernate/timestamp property

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jaxb, truncation

The scenario:

I have a servlet that receives xmls, parses them (using JAXB), persists the parsed data to a MySQL DB (using hibernate) and also saves a copy of the xml for future reference.
It saves this xml also when parsing fails. 
In these cases I receive an email with a summary of the error and then check the saved xml for clues to what went wrong.

The operation runs pretty smoothly. The servlet receives a couple of thousands xmls per day.

The problem:

At least once a day I get an error like this:

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert ..........
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '20122012-01-22 15:20:51' for column 'createdAt' at row 1
```

I get this error for some other "columns" as well.
These columns are datetime type on mysql side and `java.sql.Timestamp` on the java side.

When I take a look at the xml that was received i see the correct date format: "2012-01-22 15:20:51"

Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Looks really bizarre. I would suspect that there is another process that inserts data into this table (maybe also via Hibernate but HQL?). Try to set `org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE` log level and make sure that the source is exactly what you expect.

Comment: I'll try this in a couple of days, working on something else atm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't got this error lately.
I've recently took care of a concurrency issue with SimpleDateFormat usage so maybe that was the problem.

Comment: yup, that was it. I was parsing a jaxb value adapter to parse the timestamps and it used a non thread safe timestamp formatter. after changing to a thread safe one everything works fine.